# Why do I need a default constructor, if I never call it explicitly?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm learning a bit of C++, coming from Java...

I wrote a couple of classes, `Vector` (a 3D vector with components x, y, z) and `Bezier` (a cubic Bezier curve, based on 4 input vectors).

`Vector` works fine without defining a default constructor.

`Bezier` gives me a compilation error:

**Bezier.h**

```
class Bezier
{
  public:
    Vector p1;
    Vector cp1;
    Vector cp2;
    Vector p2;
    Bezier(const Vector &p1, const Vector &cp1, const Vector &cp2, const Vector &p2);
};
```

**Bezier.cpp**

```
Bezier::Bezier(const Vector &p1_, const Vector &cp1_, const Vector &cp2_, const Vector &p2_)
{
  p1 = p1_;
  cp1 = cp1_;
  cp2 = cp2_;
  p2 = p2_;
}
```

**Error:**

> In constructor 'Bezier::Bezier(const Vector&, const Vector&, const Vector&, const Vector&)':
>   error: no matching function for call to 'Vector::Vector()'

It seems the compiler wants me to create a default constructor `Vector()`, although I have no need for it. Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: You're missing the initializer list. And the answer to "...if I never call it explicitly?" is that you're calling it *implicitly*.

Comment: Why do you think you don't need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code (as it is now) *needs* default Vector constructor.

Look at this code again:

```
Bezier::Bezier(const Vector &p1_, const Vector &cp1_, const Vector &cp2_, const Vector &p2_)
{
  p1 = p1_;
  cp1 = cp1_;
  cp2 = cp2_;
  p2 = p2_;
}
```

What it does is that **it default-constructs all 4 vectors and *then* assigns values to them**.

If you want to get rid of default-construction step and construct these vectors with a constructor with arguments, you can write this:

```
Bezier::Bezier(const Vector &p1_, const Vector &cp1_, const Vector &cp2_, const Vector &p2_)
  : p1(p1_), cp1(cp1_), cp2(cp2_), p2(p2_)
{}
```

Answer (score 8):

When you enter the constructor, you have yet to initialize your member variables. As such, your code attempts to call the default constructor for `p1`, `cp1`, etc., so that they are initialized before it overwrites that definition according to `p1 = p1_; ...`. To tell your code to not call the default constructor at all, use `Bezier::Bezier(...) : p1(p1_), cp1(cp1_), ... {}`. This bypasses the need for the default constructor and instead initializes all instances of `Vector` via the copy constructor immediately.